# What is a block container box? Is it always a container?

Tags: css

I'm learning the [visual formatting model at W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) and I'm not sure what a block container box is:

> Except for table boxes, which are described in a later chapter, and
> replaced elements, a block-level box is also a block container box. A
> block container box either contains only block-level boxes or
> establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only
> inline-level boxes. Not all block container boxes are block-level
> boxes: non-replaced inline blocks and non-replaced table cells are
> block containers but not block-level boxes. Block-level boxes that are
> also block containers are called block boxes.

(Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes)

A box generated from an empty element like `<div></div>` would be considered a block container? For example:

```css
div {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I don't think so as it doesn't have any boxes, and to be a container it needs to contain either block level boxes or inline level boxes, right?

If it's not a block container, then wouldn't it also be a block box? What is the type of the `div` box? For example: A block level box, a block container, a block box, an inline box and so on.

Comment: It's a block box - i.e. a block-level, block-container box. The fact that it doesn't actually contain any boxes doesn't change that. Think of it as a potentially block container box if it helps. (Note that the CSS2 description is slightly out-of-date, there are some other block-level boxes that aren't block containers now, such as flex containers and grid containers.)

Comment: I see, so it would be a container because it **can** contain boxes and not necessarily have boxes inside, right?
And does a block level box mean that it participates in a block formatting context?

Comment: Yes to the first question. And yes. that's what the spec _says_ for the second question. (Although technically that excludes the box generated by the root element, which lays out following block-level box rules, but creates the first BFC, and so can't be a participant in one.)

Comment: To conclude: would an inline box be a block container? As it can contain inline box and block box

Comment: `display:inline-block` elements generate boxes that are block containers. That's what inline-block means - inline level, block container.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the elements with "display: inline", for example: "span". Are they block containers? Because I for example can do this: `<span><strong>hello</strong></span>`

Comment: Those are not block containers. A "block container" means "can contain a block box". According to the CSS2 spec, supposing you had <span>A<strong style="display:block">hello</strong>B</span> as the only contents of a div, what you'd get in the box tree would be <blockBox (anon)><inlineBox (span part 1)>A</inlineBox></blockBox><blockBox (strong)><inlineBox (anon)>hello</inlineBox></blockBox><blockBox (anon)><inlineBox (span part 2)>B</inlineBox></blockBox>. Neither span part 1 box nor span part 2 box contains the block strong element's box.

Comment: It's a fair bit different according to the CSS3 specs as it happens, but the result is logically the same.

Comment: As I understand it, inline boxes are not block containers as they cannot contain block boxes. In the example you gave, because `span` is an inline box, it cannot contain a block box (the `strong` box), so it is broken into two inline boxes, with the first box (part 1) wrapping everything that was before the strong element and with the second box (part 2) wrapping everything that was after the strong element. So, inside the `div` element we would have an inline box, a block box and an inline box.

Comment: But because now the `div` block container has a block box, we should wrap the inline boxes in anonymous block boxes resulting in `<div>(blockBox anon, has span part 1) (blockBox, has strong element) (blockBox anon, has span part 2)</div>`

Comment: Correct. Perfect.

Comment: But why can't an inline box contain block boxes? Did the specification define this explicitly? In the definition of the `display` property, it just says that `display: inline` produces inline boxes: "inline: This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes" ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)).

Comment: Looking further into the sentence "A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and therefore contains only inline-level boxes", I can say that an inline box is not a block container because it doesn't establish an inline formatting context? If so, does the content inside the box need to participate in the inline formatting context that the box itself participates in?

Comment: In [CSS2 Section 9.2.1.1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#anonymous-block-level) it says "When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) is broken around the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es)."

Comment: (continuation of my comment above) And because of that it can't contain block boxes, as block boxes must participate in a block formatting context, and because it can't contain block boxes, isn't the inline box a block container?

Comment: "I can say that an inline box is not a block container because it doesn't establish an inline formatting context?" No, because some block containers don't establish an inline formatting context. Such as block containers that only contain block-level boxes.

Comment: I think I can improve my sentence: an inline box is not a block container as it does not establish an inline formatting context (the contents of the box must participate in its inline formatting context) nor can it contain a block level box (since must participate in a block formatting context and not an inline formatting context)?

Comment: Is the rule in section 9.2.1.1 you quoted, about an inline box being split when it contains a block level box, used to maintain the rule that a block level box must participate in a block formatting context? Since the contents of an inline box must participate in the inline formatting context of the box itself.

Comment: I think those interpretations are reasonable. I'm not sure that the inline box is broken specifically for formatting context participation reasons or whether they're both the product of a common underlying reason, but it probably doesn't matter much either way.

Comment: I conclude then that:
**(I)** a **block container box** is a box that **can** contain **block boxes** (an element with **no content** `<div></div>`, for example, would still be a block container).

Comment: **(II)** An **inline box** is **not** a block container, as it **cannot** contain block boxes, because if it contains a block box it will be **split** into two boxes (according to the rule in section 9.2.2.1) and also because the **contents** of the inline box must participate in the **same inline formatting context** that contains it (the block box must participate in a **block** formatting context and not an inline context). **In addition** to not being able to have block boxes, it does **not establish an inline formatting context**, so an inline box is not a block container.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything wrong with statements I and II. Thank you very much